# How can I obtain the color of a ppm image at a (x,y) location?

Tags: c++

I am writing a code in C++ that handles the data of a ppm image . I have created a Color class that repesents a triplet of red,green, blue values and an Image class that represents a generic data container for the image . 
In my Image class I would like to have a method that obtains the color of the image at location (x,y).

My Color class is:

```
#ifndef _COLOR
#define _COLOR


namespace imaging 
{
/*! An alias for the floating point representation of color components (32bit per color channel).
 *
 * Each color channel goes from 0.0f (darkness) to 1.0f (full color brightness).
 * For example, bright red is (1,0,0), white is (1,1,1), magenta is (1,0,1) etc.
 */
typedef float component_t;

/*! Represents a triplet of Red, Green, Blue (RGB) values. 
 */ 
class Color 
{
public: 
    // members
    component_t r, //! The red color channel (component)
                g, //! The green color channel (component)
                b; //! The blue color channel (component)

    // member functions

    /*! This operator returns the index-th component of the image.
     * 
     *  For speed, no bounds for index values are checked.
     *
     *  \param index is the index of the component to obtain. Values should be 0, 1 or 2. 
     *
     *  \return a reference to the respective color component.
     */
    component_t & operator [] (size_t index)
    {
        return *(&r + index);
    }

    /*! Addition operator.
     *
     *  Adds a color to the current one and returns the result.
     *
     *  \param right is the right Color operand of the + sign. 
     *  
     *  \return the resulting color after the component-wise addition of the two colors.
     */
    Color operator + (Color & right)
    {
        Color left;
        left.r = r + right.r;
        left.g = g + right.g;
        left.b = b + right.b;
        return left;
    }

    // constructors

    /*! Parameterized constructor.
     *
     * \param r is the red component of the color.
     * \param g is the green component of the color.
     * \param b is the blue component of the color.
     */  
    Color(component_t r, component_t g, component_t b) : r(r), g(g), b(b) {}

    /*! Default constructor.
     *
     *  All components set to zero, i.e. a black color.
     */
    Color() : r(0), g(0), b(0) {}
};
}

#endif _COLOR
```

Some of my Image class is :

```
/*! The imaging namespace contains every class or function associated with the image storage, compression and manipulation.
   */
        namespace imaging
   {

//------------------------------------ class Image ------------------------------------------------

/*! It is the class that represents a generic data container for an image.
*
* It holds the actual buffer of the pixel values and provides methods for accessing them,
* either as individual pixels or as a memory block. The Image class alone does not provide
* any functionality for loading and storing an image, as it is the result or input to such a procedure.
*
* The internal buffer of an image object stores the actual bytes (data) of the color image as
* a contiguous sequence of RGB triplets. Hence, the size of the buffer variable holding these data is
* 3 X width X height X sizeof(component_t) bytes.
*
* All values stored in the internal memory buffer are floating point values and for typical (normalized)
* intensity ranges, each color component is within the range [0.0, 1.0].
*/
class Image
{
public:
    enum channel_t { RED = 0, GREEN, BLUE };          //! You can use the names RED, GREEN, BLUE instead of 0,1,2 to access individual Color channels.

protected:
    component_t * buffer;                        //! Holds the image data.

    unsigned int width,                          //! The width of the image (in pixels)
        height;                      //! The height of the image (in pixels)

public:
    // metric accessors

    /*! Returns the width of the image
    */
    const unsigned int getWidth() const { return width; }

    /*! Returns the height of the image
    */
    const unsigned int getHeight() const { return height; }

    // data accessors

    /*! Obtains a pointer to the internal data.
    *
    *  This is NOT a copy of the internal image data, but rather a pointer
    *  to the internally allocated space, so DO NOT attempt to delete the pointer.
    */
    component_t * getRawDataPtr() {
        return buffer;
    }

    /*! Obtains the color of the image at location (x,y).
    *
    *  The method should do any necessary bounds checking.
    *
    *  \param x is the (zero-based) horizontal index of the pixel to get.
    *  \param y is the (zero-based) vertical index of the pixel to get.
    *
    *  \return The color of the (x,y) pixel as a Color object. Returns a black (0,0,0) color in case of an out-of-bounds x,y pair.
    */
    Color getPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const {

    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `component_t * buffer;` contains a colour component, not a colour. Here would be a great place to use your `Color` class.

Comment: But how can I spot the x y location of the pixel?

Comment: The typical 2D to 1D mapping function is `row * number_columns + column`. In your case that would be `y * width + x` or `x * height + y` depending on the storage orientation.

Comment: I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes i tried to use mmy color class but I didnt make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
component_t * buffer;
```

requires you to assemble three separate `component_t`s into a `Color` for return by `Color getPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)`. An off by one or other math error and you will pack the wrong components into the `Color` and return bad data. However, this makes writing `component_t * getRawDataPtr()` dead easy.

To construct a `Color` from `buffer` step by step you need to:

1. Compute location of pixel: pixeloffset = y * width + x
2. There are three components per pixel, so: componentoffset = pixeloffset *3
3. So the first component of the pixel is at: pixel = buffer + componentoffset
4. Now that you know where the pixel is, you feed the pixel's `RED`, `GREEN`, and `BLUE` components into the `Color` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is the correct answer! If you have a ppm file with weight=2 and height=3 and you want to return the getpixel(2,1).
You have  (1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3) and every element has 3 components, so 
if you want the getpixel of (2,1) you have to return the 10(red),11(grey),12(blue) elements.